# Regex lookaround causing the group right after it to not be matched but matches otherwise

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-look-ahead

This is my first post on SO so thanks in advance to everyone; it's been hugely helpful to me and I'm excited for the day when I can go from being a newb to answering some questions on here! But until then:

```
/(?=((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6})\s)(\d){1,2}/

10 people will be attending the Board of Directors meeting on August 6th
```

In the RegEx above, i'm trying to match solely the '6' in August 6th and am purposefully testing it with another number in the string to make sure it doesn't get picked up. I'm struggling to understand why the lookahead is causing there to not be a match, however if we remove the lookahead, it matches "August 6".

`/((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6})\s(\d){1,2}/`

My logic is that I'm applying the lookahead to the month format and space between August and 6. Wouldn't the following group (aka the `(\d){1,2}` result in a match?

Any pointers to why I'm thinking about this wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The lookahead will only assert the starting position which is right before `August `. From there you'd still need to match anything untill the digit before actually capturing the digit. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/K9qPMF/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `(?=((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6})\s)(\d){1,2}` regex contains a `(?=((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6})\s)` positive lookahead that requires a month name (followed with whitespace) to appear immediately to the right of the current location, BUT the subsequent pattern is `(\d)` that matches a digit. Since no month name can start with a digit, this never matches any string.

The solutions can look like:

```
/\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6}\s*(\d{1,2})(?!\d)/
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/JVE6xJ/2). The value will be in Group 1. Or, since the majority of browsers aready support lookbehinds:

```
/(?<=\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6}\s*)\d{1,2}(?!\d)/
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JVE6xJ/2)

Note the `(\d){1,2}` is a wrong pattern as it captures each digit into the same capture group memory slot, and thus re-writes it all the time, and if you have `August 16`, you will still get `6` as the Group 1 value (your output).

JS demo:

```js
const regex1 = /\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6}\s*(\d{1,2})(?!\d)/;
const regex2 = /(?<=\b(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]{0,6}\s*)\d{1,2}(?!\d)/;

const text = '10 people will be attending the Board of Directors meeting on August 6th';

console.log(regex1.exec(text)[1]); // => 6
console.log(regex2.exec(text)[0]); // => 6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response and demo. This was super helpful and made me realize that I didn't have a strong grasp on lookaheads vs. lookbehinds.

Comment: Interesting point regarding the the `(\d){1,2}` grouping. So including the quantifier range inside the group is what keeps that from happening. Wouldn't the range be greedy and still capture both digits if they're there? I guess i'm just unclear on what changes between the quantifier between inside vs. outside the group.

Comment: @codingNewb23 `{1,2}` is a greedy quantifier and matches as many chars as it can. See 
 https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html